# Copy file with current time instead of metadata time

Tags: python, shutil

I am copying a file from one location to another , but the file at the new location is forming with the older time (probably when the file was created at the source system) . I am using the following command :

```
      shutil.copy2(filename , BACKUP_DIRECTORY)
```

How can I copy the file (I do not want to move the file) with the current time stamp.

Answer (score 2):

As given [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) shutil.copy2 will copy metadata also where as shutil.copy will not copy the meta data. I also verified that it creates a new time stamp when you use shutil.copy.